# Is it possible to cancel download of a remote AVPlayerItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, avfoundation

Is it possible to cancel the download of a remote `AVPlayerItem` without removing or stopping the video from the player itself?

I've tried `[item.asset cancelLoading]`, but it doesn't seem to be the right method for this (it appears to be for the `AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading` portions of `AVAsset`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I filed a TSI for this and received the following response:

> I spoke with our AV Foundation engineers about this, and no, it is not
>   possible to cancel the download of a remote AVPlayerItem without
>   removing or stopping the video from the player itself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have the *AVPlayer* which plays a list of items and you want to add another item from remote source.

When you create a new *AVPlayerItem* with *+playerItemWithURL:* or *–initWithURL:* method, it is immediately returns the item, but with the status AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown.

You should wait until the status will be changed to *AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay* before adding this item to your *AVPlayer* playlist. Thus you could simply release this *AVPlayerItem* in case of *AVPlayerItemStatusFailed* status or timeout exceeding and your player would play all the rest videos without stopping.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear about my question. I was specifically asking if it was possible to cancel any further download of an AVPlayerItem that is already playing, without stopping it. I filed a TSI and am updating the post with the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on sevenflow's answer: When you want to stop an AVPlayerItem from loading, use AVQueuePlayer's removeAllItems and then re-initialize it.

```
  [self.avPlayer removeAllItems];
  self.avPlayer = [AVQueuePlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
  self.avPlayer = nil;
```

This will stop the current item from loading -- it is the only way I found to accomplish this.